# Why does mysqli() not recognize my database name?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to PHP and MySQL. While learning, I got this error that says my database is unkown.

I have already made this database.

[image]

and I have already made the table 'todos'

[image]

Here is my PHP

```
<?php

require 'functions.php';

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','', 'mytodo');
    
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    
    $statement = $conn->prepare('select * from todos');

    $statement->execute();

    var_dump($statement->fetchAll());
    

require 'index.view.php';
```

the PHP file is named 'Index.test.php'

but when I try to access localhost/Index.test.php on my browser

it returns this

[image]

Could you tell me why I am getting the error? Appreciate the help!

Comment: in the command line everything looks fine. Can you run queries OK on your `todo` table?

Comment: Do you have two databases installed? Are you using correct port/socket?

Answer (score -3):

try to use this select:

```
<?php

require 'functions.php';

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','', 'mytodo');
    
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    
    //select query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM todos";
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['your column name']; 
}


//free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
echo "no records found";
}
}

else {
echo "error: could not connect" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
    

require 'index.view.php';   
?>
```